# javascript regex shortcode wordpress

Tags: javascript, regex, wordpress, tinymce, shortcode

Suppose I have shortcode such these:

```
[lexio param1="ara" param2="baba"]content[/lexio]

[tagor param1="rara"]
```

How to extract them all with javascript regex? I want lexio params data, and content. I need tagor and its param too.

I tried

```
/[([a-z]+)([^[]+)*(?:](.*)[\/\1]|\s+\/])/gm;
```

but this didn't work.

Thanks

**EDIT 1:**

I find the regex pattern:

```
/(.?)\[([\w\-]+)\b((?:[^\[\]]|(?R)|.)*?)(?:(\/))?\](?:(.+?)\[\/\2\])?(.?)/gm
```

But how to extract that pattern like preg_match_all in php?

Comment: `code`o.content.match/\[([a-z]+)([^[]+)*(?:\](.*)\[\/\1\]|\s+\/\])/gm;

Comment: fyi http://regexpal.com/ is a handy tool to test regular expressions.

Comment: Ok thanks, but i still looking for the solutions

Answer (score 0):

***JavaScript:***

```
var regex = /\](.*?)\[/g, result = []; 

while ( (result = regex.exec(text)) ) { 
  print(result[1]);
}
```

*See and test the code [here](http://ideone.com/7IxtO).*

Comment: Your pattern didn't solve my problem. It just extract the content between enclosed shortcodes tag.